# To get historical data of memory consumption by a particular process before it gets stopped

Tags: debugging, out-of-memory, profiling, profiler, vmmap

I have a process (it is a windows service). It throws bad_alloc exception and stops. Later it is being started by another monitoring tool. I want to see the memory related details specific to that process just before it stops.

The tools like Process explorer, VMmap can be used for running processes. But, as my process stops we loose the data here. Is there any way to log the data of this process till it stops/ till some time period?

I tried 2 options in VMmap for the same.

(a) View Running process option works fine, but it needs regular 'Refresh' from user and During refresh if the process is stopped/restarted (now it is with new PID) the previous data are lost.

(b) Launch and trace a new process(here I have option of auto refresh after each second) -But it is not able to initiate my windows service.

Could you please suggest if there are any other ways for it?

I referred multiple articles for this , but none of them helped in my case.

The reason to capture logs is- these services are in production system on customer machines, so cannot analyse at the time of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Performance Monitor (PerfMon) to capture data specific to my process for every 10 minutes. It gives me both historic data as well as the current data.